# Regex doesn't see my second alternative as valid

Tags: regex

I am new at this, and sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to figure out why my regex `(11*|0?10*)*` doesn't see the number 110 as valid.

As I see it, I can take a 1 from the first alternative and then 10 from the second thus getting 110, but regex checkers do not see this as true. I am missing something?

Comment: Your regex does not match 0, that's why..

Comment: You can force it with this `\b(11*|0?10*)*\b` The reason lies in between your regex and this one. Try to work out why that is so. Hint: `(0?10*|11*)*` matches 110

Comment: There is a good site here that would help you understant better the regex process. https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html I bet it's a small misunderstanting between * and \d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` operator indicates an alternative pattern that might match the string. You have two alternatives but “110” isn't matched by either `11*` or `0?10*`.

Because your alternatives are repeated with the outer `*` operator you can get partial matches from each alternative. But `11*` will capture the “11” in “110”, leaving only a “0” behind, which isn't matched by either `11*` or `0?10*`.

If you want far too much detail on the subject, check this out: https://www.rexegg.com/

You haven't said what you're looking to match, but it seems like you want to match any iteration of zeroes and ones, so `[01]+` would seem to be your best bet.